# Что - вопросительное или относительное местоимение?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем является "что" в предложении:

> Мать пока не знала, **что** она предпочла бы для сына.

Oпределила это слово как вопросительное местоимение (но одновременно сомневаюсь что это может быть относительное местоимение?) Если это все-таки вопросительное местоимение, можно сказать что это омо́ним с союзом "что" (Я не знал, что он инженер.)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Мать пока не знала, что она предпочла бы для сына.**

**ЧТО** ― **относительное местоимение в роли союзного слова.** В отличие от союза, союзное слово является членом предложения (дополнением в данном случае).

**Я не знала, что он инженер.**

ЧТО ― **союз, служебное слово,** служит для связи предложений. **Союз ЧТО является омонимом** местоимения ЧТО (вопросительного и относительного).

ОМОНИМ ― слово, совпадающее с другим словом по звучанию и написанию, но расходящееся по значению и системе форм.

**Пояснение**

1) Существуют **два вида классификации слов:** какая часть речи? какой член предложения? Части речи бывают **знаменательные** (существительное, прилагательное, глагол, местоимение и др.) и **служебные** (предлоги, частицы союзы).

2) В предложении части речи играют определенную роль: знаменательные части речи являются **членами предложения** (подлежащее, сказуемое, дополнение и др.), а служебные  предназначены для других целей (в частности, союзы служат для связи слов и предложений).

3) Местоимения делятся по значению на 9 разрядов, среди них есть **вопросительные**  (используются в простых вопросительных предложениях) и **относительные** (те же местоимения в сложноподчиненных предложениях в роли члена предложения).

4) **Слово ЧТО может быть союзом,** то есть служебной частью речи, служащей только для связи предложений и не являющейся членом предложения.

5) **Слово ЧТО может быть вопросительным или относительным местоимением.** Если это относительное местоимение, то оно выполняет две функции: служит для связи предложений в качестве **союзного слова** и является членом предложения.

Answer (score 2):

В предложении " *Мать пока не знала,* **что**  *она предпочла бы для сына"* относительное местоимение **"что"** выполняет функцию союзного слова, на него падает логическое ударение.  Вопросительные местоимения употребляются в вопросительных предложениях.А относительные местоимения служат для связей частей сложного предложения, между этими частями устанавливается подчинительная связь.

Ср.: Что произошло? Я не знала,что произошло. В первом примере "что" является вопросительным местоимением, а во втором - относительным местоимением.